# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers' how to solve

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikeras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNsm.png)

The module keras.wrappershas been removed in tensorflow 2.15, so its normal you don't find it.

You have the last version of adapt (0.4.4) so the bug doesn't come from the adapt library.

Your issue comes from this import :

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
```

You should replace this line with:

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
```

we try this but yet it didnt happen